# Rotate UIButton randomly on screen

Tags: iphone, uibutton, core-animation, rotation, cakeyframeanimation

I want to rotate a button randomly on a screen. No specific path defined it can move randomly on a view.

I dont want to use CAKeyframeAnimation. It should be clean and simple.

Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate the button's `transform` property using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` and combine it with an `NSTimer` with a random time interval.

Comment: If i will use arc4random then button rotation will be jerky, How can i make it smooth rotation in 320*480 view ?

Answer (score 1):

```
CGAffineTransform cachedTransform = transformedView.transform;
transformedView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

// Note each of the (untransformed) points of interest.
CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(0, 0);
CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(0, transformedView.frame.size.height);
CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(transformedView.frame.size.width, transformedView.frame.size.height);
CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(transformedView.frame.size.width, 0);

// Re-apply the transform.
transformedView.transform = cachedTransform;

// Use handy built-in UIView methods to convert the points.
topLeft = [transformedView convertPoint:topLeft toView:parentView];
bottomLeft = [transformedView convertPoint:bottomLeft toView:parentView];
bottomRight = [transformedView convertPoint:bottomRight toView:parentView];
topRight = [transformedView convertPoint:topRight toView:parentView];
```

Also see if this link is useful to you : [Moving UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759589/moving-uibutton-around)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity,
     RADIANS(30.0));

myButton.transform = rotateTransform;
```

Use NSTimer to carry this process and use arc4random to randomly generate the angle in radians.

Comment: this code will rotate button at the same origin. I want to rotate button in 320*480 view.